# how to make overlay with activity indicator programatically

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiactivityindicatorview

i need to set the activity indicator with the blur overlay background in objective c.How to do that.

I tried this code but not able to set overlay for view.Note that i have only view controller with one button.After press that button i need to make a overlay with the activity indicator.

```
 spinner = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(150, 225, 20, 30)];
    [spinner setActivityIndicatorViewStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleGray];
    spinner.center = CGPointMake([[UIScreen mainScreen]bounds].size.width/2, [[UIScreen mainScreen]bounds].size.height/2);
    spinner.color = [UIColor redColor];
    [self.view addSubview:spinner];
```

How to do that ??

Comment: Try this library  instead, https://github.com/SVProgressHUD/SVProgressHUD

Comment: I should not use any 3rd party library

Comment: make a overlay or make a blur backgound for viewcontroler

Comment: Instead of centering your spinner based on screen bounds why don't you just say `spinner.center = self.view.center;` Also what exactly are you asking? How to blur self.view ?

Comment: i need to add overlay with out 3rd party library or i need to make one small view at centre and inside that  i need to keep my activity indicator

Answer (score 1):

This is what i did in one of my projects long time back. :)

Tag of the view:

```
#define TAG_BGVIEW 182


/*
 *********************************************************
 This method creates the activity alert on the view and
 sets its center to the center of the specified view
 *********************************************************
 */
+ (void)showActivityIndicatorOnView:(UIView*)view withCenter:(CGRect)frame withText:(NSString*)text {

    [view setUserInteractionEnabled:NO];


    UIView *backgroundView = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, frame.size.height / 2 -70, 300, 170)];
    backgroundView.tag = TAG_BGVIEW;
    [backgroundView.layer setCornerRadius:5.0f];
    [backgroundView.layer setBorderWidth:2.0f];
    [backgroundView.layer setBorderColor:[UIColor blackColor].CGColor];
    [backgroundView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
    [backgroundView setAlpha:0.8f];

    UIActivityIndicatorView *spinner = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleWhiteLarge];

    [spinner startAnimating];
    spinner.center = CGPointMake(backgroundView.frame.size.width / 2, backgroundView.frame.size.height / 2);


    UILabel *indicatorLabel = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(frame.size.width / 2, frame.size.height / 2 + spinner.frame.size.height + 15, 300, 40)];
    [indicatorLabel setText:text];
    [indicatorLabel setTextAlignment:NSTextAlignmentCenter];
    [indicatorLabel setNumberOfLines:0];
    [indicatorLabel setFont:[AppStyle getTableViewCellFont]];
    [indicatorLabel setTextColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
    indicatorLabel.center  = CGPointMake(backgroundView.frame.size.width / 2, backgroundView.frame.size.height / 2 + spinner.frame.size.height + 10);

    [view addSubview:backgroundView];
    [backgroundView addSubview:spinner];
    [backgroundView addSubview:indicatorLabel];
}
```

This is how you can stop it:

```
/*
 *********************************************************
 This method stops the activity indicator visible on
 the screen
 *********************************************************
 */
+ (void)stopActivityIndicatorOnView:(UIView*)view {

    for (UIView *currentView in view.subviews) {


        if ([currentView isKindOfClass:[UIView class]]) {

            UIView *view = (UIView*)currentView;

            if (view.tag == TAG_BGVIEW) {
                [view removeFromSuperview];
            }

        }

    }

    [view setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
}
```

Comment: how can i call this method after press button action

Comment: i need to call this method  inside my button action

Comment: Copy this code inside a your .m file. Then call this method using `[YourClassName stopActivityIndicatorOnView:self.view]`